# Tag dropdown displays misleading counts for some tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, tag-dropdown

I was editing [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13595424/331508), and momentarily thought about tagging it as an undocumented "feature".  I saw this in the tag dropdown:

[image: Bug tag counts]

So, [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is a valid tag with a legit-looking excerpt and hundreds of questions, right?

Except I vaguely remember a jihad against [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), here on Meta, so I clicked on the "*learn more*" link, and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug):

[image: bug count]

The other tags ([debugging](/questions/tagged/debugging), [xdebug](/questions/tagged/xdebug), etc.) have counts that match or seem accurate to within an hour or so.

I searched Meta for indications that [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) was being purged, but searches for "bug" [don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D%20%2bbug) [work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D%20%2bbug%20%2bdelete&submit=search) [so well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D%20%2bbug%20%2bburninate&submit=search). ;-)   (One reason why having the tag would be useful.)

So:

1. Did 267 questions get retagged or deleted in just an hour or two (or even a day)?  And this is just a query/display delay?
2. Or is this a query/display bug?
3. Is there a purge on this tag, and if so where's the Meta post?
4. Can we get a tag wiki that sticks for zero-count tags.  So that a "Do not use this tag" message can be preserved?

Comment: It actually looks like an issue with search. There [are 267 questions with that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+views%3A0).

Comment: Logs like a bug in the bug tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed; 'twas a glitch when the target tag didn't actually exist; bug used to be a synonym of bugs. I've deleted the synonym as part of my investigation, but I've fixed the underlying problem too.