# How can the [bug] tag have both zero questions and over 280?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I recently edited [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) out of a question.  Infuriated by the tag existing, I went to see what kind of horrible, horrible questions it contained so I could whip up a burninate/ban request.

It contains ... no questions.

[image: ZARRO BOOGS]

But, on the tag sidebar in the question I edited, it clearly states that there are over 280 questions in it.  You can see this for yourself.  Visit the [SO tag list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and enter "bug" into the filter box.

[image: NON-ZARRO BOOGS]

What's going on here?  Some sort of tag hellban or honeypot?  Dare I call this a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)?  It's been like this for a while (*weeks*), but I've ignored it assuming that it, itself, was some sort of display or caching artifact and that it'd pass with time.

---

Additional clues from the comments:

- The "recent hot answers" section [inside the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) shows a small number of questions.
- A search for `[bug]+` shows results.

---

It looks like the [calculate](/questions/tagged/calculate) tag is doing the same thing.  Three questions listed when viewed from inside the question, but zero questions in the question list.

Comment: It probably just got purged, and the numbers haven't synced.

Comment: It's been like this for *weeks*, I just hadn't ever caught any questions with the tag.  There's no way that this was a recent purge and/or the result of caching.

Comment: Ah... missed your last sentence.

Comment: The system obviously knows there are [bug]-tagged questions out there, because it notes "7 asked today, 32 this week" under the tag description, there. The "Recent hot answers" list functions properly, too, bringing up [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610903/matlab-floor-bug/12611769#12611769) (among others). And yet, I also see an empty page when "newest" is selected. Crazy!

Comment: What is this "Recent hot answers" of which you speak?

Comment: The [bug] tag on Meta has quite a few questions!

Comment: It appears to be some special case with the tag itself, as it only does it when you're on the `/tags` or `/tagged` pages. But a search for [`[bug]+`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%2B) returns all 281 results. :)

Comment: @Charles it's in the sidebar of the tag wiki ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYxg.png))

Comment: What top-level button did you recently push?

Comment: @Rosinante, as is very clearly seen in the screenshots, I was then on the "newest" tab.  None of the other tabs have any results either.  Given the funny search results given by Popular Demand and animuson, I expect this to be specific behavior given to the tag by the system, not the usual "oops, I was on a tab that gives no content" problem.

Comment: The tag just wants to live up to its name.

Comment: Less direct report of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157026/tag-dropdown-displays-misleading-counts-for-some-tags

Comment: The bug tag has a bug, and now we're discussing it on Meta? How very meta.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoDisagreesWithYou And now we're discussing it's meta-ness. How (even more) meta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The UI is right... for a certain definition of right. There is a synonym in play here: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) has been forwarded to [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs). But just to add confusion, there **is** no [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) - the tag doesn't even exist (we purge redundant tags). It looks like the fact that the target-tag doesn't *exist* stopped the entire synonym working, which is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (note the different border). I'll look into that.

Even though ["bug" says it doesn't have any synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/synonyms), the [master synonym list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) disagreed (past tense; see below)

[image]

which shows that 245 haven't been merged. I have deleted that synonym - it clearly wasn't needed. You now have access to the 245 phantom questions. I still need to fix a few places where synonyms are checked, to ensure it works properly for cases where the target doesn't exist.

Comment: Btw: we can add bug => bugs back in if people want it: I mainly deleted it as a quick fix and to validate my suspicion. Deploying the *actual* fix currently.

Comment: Thanks Marc!  While you're poking around in there, you'd may as well just nuke the tag.  Otherwise I'll be filing a burnination request later today.