# Burninate the facebooksdk tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I found the [facebooksdk](/questions/tagged/facebooksdk) tag which seems to be a dublicate of [facebook-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-sdk) which was merged with [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook). I think that tag is not usefull at all.

Comment: There are only twelve questions tagged [facebooksdk]. That's low enough that they can be retagged to [facebook] manually. That'll make [facebooksdk] unused, and unused tags are deleted after 24 hours.

Comment: Bloody hell, I thought I nuked that thing.  *Twice*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I retagged all the questions under the tag, although I'm curious how the tag got created in the first place. The oldest question with the tag was asked on December 12th, so it had to have been created recently. But according to their rules, creating a tag that only differs from another tag by the addition of a hyphen is not allowed. This leads me to believe that the rule may possibly not be applied to tags which are only synonyms to other tags. Definitely something worth looking into, and fixing at that.

Comment: Could be related to the nature of the FSO tag filtering site... There have been some  [oddities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site) there before.

Comment: This isn't the first time we've had a phantom synonyms causing trouble recently.  Recently [bug/bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157453/135887) was a thing, and [game/game-development](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/154731/135887) has also sprung back to life...

Comment: @Charles: This one is slightly different than those, because by all standards it *shouldn't* be createable once it's dead.

Comment: @animuson, indeed, but if `game` and `game-development` are also synonyms, why are people able to create new `game-development` questions?  I suspect that `facebooksdk` was synonymized *before* the hyphen ban happened and is allowed to exist now only because something in the synonym system is busted.

Comment: I'm confused... [tag:game] is a synonym of [tag:game-development], so what exactly would prevent new questions?

Comment: I'm confused also.  Not a few days ago, it was reversed.